# Druid 0.17 native parallel ingestion with orc files

Tags: druid, orc

Did any one experience this:
I'm trying to run a native parallel batch ingestion from s3 to druid. the inputFormat is orc.
I deployed druid 0.17 cluster and enable the druid-orc-extensions.
when running the ingestion task I receive on the sub task the following exception:
org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo - Could not read 'common-version-info.properties', java.io.IOException: Resource not found

it looks as if something is wrong with the hadoop-common loading, but on the log I see that it was loaded when the extension is loaded, is it a known issue?

I also opened a druid issue for it: https://github.com/apache/druid/issues/9408

Thanks

Comment: Have you got any solution for the issue?